# Updating or rendering a view from a viewModel WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

OK, so here is my problem: 
I have a WPF application where I am using the Mvvm pattern. In the main window I have a TabControl that is bound to a collection of viewmodels. The Tabcontrol uses contenttemplate to describe each view using a separate usercontrol.

Now I would like to save each view in the tabcontrol to a png image (for example) using a button. The problem is 
1) How do I tell the itemcollection to save each view?
2) How do I get the views to render (or to bind to their respectively datacontext) without specifially clicking on each tabitem?

I have tried using message handlers in order to resolve the first question, however, since all of the tabitems have not been bound to their datacontexts it means that the second question is hard to solve.

Here is an example: 
My main view model:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase {


    public ObservableCollection<SubViewModel> Units { get; private set; }

    public ICommand OnPrintSaveCommand { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel() {
        Units = new ObservableCollection<SubViewModel>
        {
            new SubViewModel(1, "Task 1"),
            new SubViewModel(2, "Task 2"),
            new SubViewModel(3, "Task 3"),
        };

        OnPrintSaveCommand = new RelayCommand( p => PrintSave());
    }

    private void PrintSave() {

        foreach (var subViewModel in Units) {
            subViewModel.OnPrintSave("SomeFileName.bmp");
        }

    }
}
```

Then I have the sub view model:

```
public delegate void SaveToPngEventHandler(object sender, SaveToPngEventArgs eventArgs);

public class SubViewModel : ViewModelBase {

    public int UnitNumber { get; private set; }
    public string Unitname { get; private set; }

    private event SaveToPngEventHandler SaveToPngHandler;
    public SaveToPngEventHandler OnSaveToPng { get { return SaveToPngHandler; } set { SaveToPngHandler = value; } }

    public SubViewModel(int unitNumber, string unitname) {
        UnitNumber = unitNumber;
        Unitname = unitname;

        DisplayName = string.Format("{0} - {1}", unitNumber, unitname);
    }

    public void OnPrintSave(string somefilenameBmp) {
        if (OnSaveToPng != null) {
            OnSaveToPng(this, new SaveToPngEventArgs(somefilenameBmp));
        }
    }
}
```

and finally the mainwindow here:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="UnitTemplate" DataType="local:SubViewModel">
        <local:ItemView/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="TabItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Border x:Name="Border" CornerRadius="5,0,0,5" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="10">
                        <Grid x:Name="grd">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="tb1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding DisplayName}" Margin="2"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="tb2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding UnitNumber}" Margin="2"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="tb3" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Unitname}" Margin="2"/>

                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="tb1" Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="tb2" Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="tb3" Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TabControl Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Units}" TabStripPlacement="Left" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource UnitTemplate}"/>

    <Button Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Print/save" Margin="5" Command="{Binding OnPrintSaveCommand}"></Button>
</Grid>
```

and the separate viewcontrol for the subviewmodel:

```
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
    <Border CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="10">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding DisplayName}" Margin="10"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding UnitNumber}" Margin="10"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Unitname}" Margin="10"/>

        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

with the code behind:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for ItemView.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class ItemView : UserControl {
    public ItemView() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs) {
        var viewModel = DataContext as SubViewModel;
        if (viewModel != null) {
            viewModel.OnSaveToPng += OnSaveToPng;
            // Will only reach this point if tabitem has been clicked
        }
    }

    private void OnSaveToPng(object sender, SaveToPngEventArgs eventArgs) {
        // Get MainGrid and save it here

        var canvas = new Canvas();
        //canvas.Children.Add(MainGrid);
        // etc..
    }
}
```

In order to run this you'll also need the following classes:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand {
    #region Fields

    readonly Action<object> _execute;
    readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    #endregion // Fields

    #region Constructors

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null) {
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute) {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }
    #endregion // Constructors

    #region ICommand Members

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter) {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

    #endregion // ICommand Members
}

public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    #region Property Changed

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion
}


public class SaveToPngEventArgs : EventArgs {
    public string FilePath { get; private set; }

    public SaveToPngEventArgs(string filePath) {
        FilePath = filePath;
    }
}
```